# How to give a numeric value to an object while writing an rdf triple

Tags: rdf, rdfs, linked-data, turtle-rdf, triples

I am tryin to write an rdf triple for
`MixedFruitJuice is made of 2 Oranges, 1 Pomegranate and 1 Pineapple`.

Here`MixedFruitJuice` is an instance of class `FruitJuice`and `Orange` `Pomegranate` and `Pineapple` are instances of `Fruit`.

I don't understand how I can give a numeric value to the objects. Like "2" oranges, or "1" Pomegranate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to achieve this. For example, using OWL, you can apply `owl:Restriction` to define either an `rdfs:subClass` or an `owl:equivalentClass`, depending if you see your recipe as necessary or as necessary and sufficient conditions for a `MixedFruitJuice`.

I would suggest declaring `Orange`, `Pomegranate` and `Pineapple` as `rdfs:subClass` of `Fruit`. This way a concrete juice, if made of concrete fruits according to the recipe, could be `MixedFruitJuice`. Now, assuming necessary but insufficient conditions (after all they'd also need some shaking), a `:MixedFruitJuice` can be described as:

```
:MixedFruitJuice rdf:type owl:Class ;
          rdfs:subClassOf [ owl:intersectionOf ( :Juice
                 [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                 owl:onProperty :hasIngredient ;
                 owl:qualifiedCardinality "1"^^xsd:nonNegativeInteger ;
                 owl:onClass :Pineapple]
                 [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                 owl:onProperty :hasIngredient ;
                 owl:qualifiedCardinality "1"^^xsd:nonNegativeInteger ;
                 owl:onClass :Pomegranate]
                 [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                 owl:onProperty :hasIngredient ;
                 owl:qualifiedCardinality "2"^^xsd:nonNegativeInteger ;
                 owl:onClass :Orange]
                                                          ) ;
                                       rdf:type owl:Class
                                     ] .
```

Apart from OWL, this can be achieved also with SHACL in some cases, bringing better results.

If you want to keep `Orange`, `Pomegranate` and `Pineapple` as instances and not as subclasses of `Fruit`, then you may consider using RDF reification or RDF*.

Using reification can create problems and anyway there is a simple way to represent it, using just RDF, which I should've thought of before suggesting OWL. Here it is:

```
:MixedFruitJuice
  rdf:type :Juice ;
  :isMadeOf [
      rdf:type :Orange ;
      :numberOfUnits "2"^^xsd:decimal ;
    ] ;
  :isMadeOf [
      rdf:type :Pineapple ;
      :numberOfUnits "1"^^xsd:decimal ;
    ] ;
  :isMadeOf [
      rdf:type :Pomegranate ;
      :numberOfUnits "1"^^xsd:decimal ;
    ] ;
.
```

For `:numberOfUnits` I could've chosen an `xsd:int` range but I assume that in juices might require 1.5 apples for example.

Comment: Thanks, I would really like to get some insights on RDF reification.

Comment: Well, that would be giving a count to a type statement, but that'snot really an elegant solution. In fact, there is a very simple RDF solution with which I updated my answer.